# how to return sliced element from an mongodb array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have a list of data in an array of size 250 MB. Every time when I query, the full 250 data is downloaded even I am slicing the data.
here is my code

```
DomainsApi.findOne({}, {auction_list:{$slice:[10, 20]}}, (err, doc)=>{
  if(doc){
    console.log(doc)
  }
})
```

I want only 10 item from the **auction_list** array but its not working. the full 250 MB data is downloading everytime and eating my bandwidth and time.

I checked the mongodb docs but that didn't help me.

How can I achieve that? I am on node js and using mongodb atlas free account.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: refer [$slice projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/operator/projection/slice/).

Comment: Which tool do you use in nodejs to work with Mongo: mongoose, mongodb, etc.?

Comment: Mongodb node js

Comment: @turivishal I tried, but it returning whole array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use aggregate. Check this please:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      slicedArray: {
        $slice: [
          "$auction_list",
          10
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CP7LMXOj8lj)

Comment: `db.collectioni.find({}).project({auction_list:{$slice:[0,1]}})` This is also working. Am I right way?

Comment: Yes @IrfanHabib , pretty much the same thing you did and I wrote.

Comment: One thing here is the [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) about slice, why its not working when I query through `db.collection.findI({}, {auction_list:{$slice:[2,4]}})`